# How do I compare two timestamps as dates in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to run a query to bring back that occurred on or after a date where the input date is a timestamp and the and the table is a timestamp. The problem i have is right now results are getting excluded based on time so some go missing. Refer to below sample for details

Sample SQL

```
Select *
from table
where DateTime >= InputDateTime
```

Sample Table

```
Row | DateTime
1   | 2015-01-16 23:12:11
2   | 2015-01-15 06:12:24
3   | 2015-01-14 23:12:24
4   | 2015-01-15 23:12:24
5   | 2015-01-12 23:12:24
```

Expected result if InputDateTime =  2015-01-15 12:13:24

```
Row | DateTime
1   | 2015-01-16 23:12:11
2   | 2015-01-15 06:12:24
4   | 2015-01-15 23:12:24
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to consider only the date, then remove the time component:

```
where datetime >= cast(getdate() as date)
```

Of courese, you can do this for a variable or column as well:

```
where datetime >= cast(@inputdatetime as date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Now that I understand that you are wanting to compare based solely off of date, I am changing my code to reflect a way to do so:

```
DECLARE @inputDateTime DATETIME = '2015-01-15 12:13:24'

-- DROP TABLE [#testTable]
CREATE TABLE [#testTable]
(
[Row] INT IDENTITY(1,1),
[DateTime] DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO [#testTable]
    (
    [DateTime]
    )
VALUES
    ('2015-01-16 23:12:11'),
    ('2015-01-15 06:12:24'),
    ('2015-01-14 23:12:24'),
    ('2015-01-15 23:12:24'),
    ('2015-01-12 23:12:24')

SELECT
    *
FROM
    [#testTable]
WHERE
    [DateTime] >= CONVERT(DATETIME,FLOOR(CONVERT(FLOAT,@inputDateTime)))
```

Comment: The 2015-01-15 12:13:24 is supposed to be midday which in is after 6 am e.g. 12:13 PM. Its the same day but would get excluded if it was a time stamp comparison

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean now, then just truncate your inputDateTime variable at comparison:

DECLARE @inputDateTime DATETIME = '2015-01-15 12:13:24'

-- DROP TABLE [#testTable]
CREATE TABLE [#testTable]
(
[Row] INT IDENTITY(1,1),
[DateTime] DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO [#testTable]
 (
 [DateTime]
 )
VALUES
 ('2015-01-16 23:12:11'),
 ('2015-01-15 06:12:24'),
 ('2015-01-14 23:12:24'),
 ('2015-01-15 23:12:24'),
 ('2015-01-12 23:12:24')

SELECT
 *
FROM
 [#testTable]
WHERE
 [DateTime] >= CONVERT(DATETIME,FLOOR(CONVERT(FLOAT,@inputDateTime)))